# Oracle : SQL query that choose all values when no input for IN clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query using an IN clause. How would I execute to choose all values if there is no input for the bind variable?

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, employee_number
FROM employee 
WHERE employee_number IN (:p_employee_num)
```

Comment: Does that code work for 1, or more input values?

Comment: It can work for more input values, lets assume if I use the inputs 1,2,3 - the in clause would then search for 1,2,3

Comment: You need separate bind variables for each value you want to search. If you pass 1,2,3 as your bind (it would need to be a string) you’d be looking for where the value of employee_number was the string '1,2,3', that probably isn’t what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You may add logic to the `WHERE` clause which also allows a null bind variable:

```sql
SELECT first_name, last_name, employee_number
FROM employee 
WHERE employee_number IN (:p_employee_num) OR :p_employee_num IS NULL;
```

For a `NULL` bind variable, the `IN` clause above would never be true, but the `IS NULL` check would always be true, thereby returning every record.

Comment: Thanks for your help. If I have multiple conditions, it seems to retrieve every record and ignores the other conditions I put in place. How would I retrieve every record with the other filters I put and just ignore the values for the employee number?

Comment: You need to use the OR condition in brackets as follows: `(employee_number IN (:p_employee_num) OR :p_employee_num IS NULL) AND ...`

Answer (score 0):

One method would be:

```
WITH e as (
      SELECT first_name, last_name, employee_number
      FROM employee 
      WHERE employee_number IN (:p_employee_num)
     )
SELECT first_name, last_name, employee_number
FROM e
UNION ALL
SELECT first_name, last_name, employee_number
FROM employee
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM e);
```